# How to do an inclusion AND exclusion join query in SQL/Active Record?

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails, postgresql, activerecord

**The Problem**

I have three models, greatly simplified for the purpose of this question:

```
User:
- id

Event:
- id
- user_id (FK)

Stream:
- id
- event_id (FK)
- user_id (FK)
```

I'm using PostgresQL

Lets say I have two users, with IDs: 1, 2.

I want to retrieve all Events that has at least one Stream by User 1.  I also want to exclude any Events that have at least one Stream by User 2.

**Data Set**

```
Stream: ID: 1, User: 1, Event: 1
Stream: ID: 2, User: 1, Event: 1
Stream: ID: 3, User: 1, Event: 2
Stream: ID: 4, User: 2, Event: 2
Stream: ID: 5, User: 2, Event: 3
Stream: ID: 6, User: 2, Event: 3
```

For purposes of this example, let's say these are all of the Streams in the system.

**Current Active Record Query**

```
# Keep in mind this is on the User model.  So self=User 1

Event.joins(:streams)
    .merge( Stream.where(user: self).where.not(user: User.find(2)) )
    .....
```

Resulting Query:

```
SELECT events.*
FROM events
INNER JOIN streams ON streams.event_id = events.id
WHERE streams.user_id = 1 AND streams.user_id != 2
```

**Current Result**

Expected:

```
Event 1
```

Actual:

```
Event 1
Event 2
```

Currently this appropriately only returns Events having at least one Stream by User 1, however it does not exclude those Events which also have at least one Stream by User 2.

How can you properly execute this in SQL, and an unnecessary bonus, in Active Record?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this

```
SELECT events.*
FROM events ev
INNER JOIN streams st
ON st.event_id = ev.id
and st.user_id = 1 
left join streams st1
ON st1.event_id = ev.id
and st1.user_id = 2
where st1.event_id is null
```

Comment: Hey! This appears to work.  If you don't mind and you have a spare moments, I'd love to know _why_ this works.  Why does the IS NULL cancel out the events having streams with user_id=2?

Comment: In first join with streams table, we are fetching records whose userid =1 and in left join we are checking if there are any events with userid = 1 also have events with User 2. So IS NULL is to eliminate those type of records

Comment: I also discovered that with this method, the order of the AND statements matter (only with outer joins).  So in this case, the AND st.user_id=1 has to be before the left join, and the others after.